# How to make literal type optional in Record<Keys, Type>

Tags: typescript

Based on [typescript reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype):

```
interface PageInfo {
  title: string;
}

type Page = "home" | "about" | "contact";

const nav: Record<Page, PageInfo> = {
  about: { title: "about" },
  contact: { title: "contact" },
  home: { title: "home" },
};
```

I want to be able to define various `Record<Page, PageInfo>` something like that:

```
const nav: Record<Page, PageInfo> = {
  about: { title: "about" },
  contact: { title: "contact" }
};
```

In that I Error `Property 'home' is missing in type '{ about: { title: string; }; contact: { title: string; }; }' but required in type 'Record<Page, PageInfo>'.`

So how would you make it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use `Partial`, which makes all properties of a type optional:

```
const nav: Partial<Record<Page, PageInfo>> = {
  about: { title: "about" },
  contact: { title: "contact" }
}
```

[Link to more info on Partial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html)